# How to make diaglog box and get all user input to do the math?

Tags: java, dialog

I am trying to add dialog box by showing the question and answer box for user to put but i got no chance to make it work i had used showmessagedialog but it only print the question and user input but it cannot get user's input and do the math, so here is my code without dialog

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");
    int firstnumber = keyboard.nextInt();  //scan first input number

    System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");
    int secondnumber = keyboard.nextInt();  //scan second input number

    int sum= firstnumber + secondnumber;  //sum the first number and second number
    System.out.println("" + firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " + sum);

    int minus= firstnumber - secondnumber;  //minus the first number and second number
    System.out.println("" + firstnumber + " - " + secondnumber + " = " + minus);

    int multiply= firstnumber * secondnumber;  //multiply the first number and second number
    System.out.println("" + firstnumber + " * " + secondnumber + " = " + multiply);

    int divide= firstnumber / secondnumber;  //divide the first number and second number
    System.out.println("" + firstnumber + " / " + secondnumber + " = " + divide);

    int moddivide= firstnumber % secondnumber; // modulus divide the first and second number
    System.out.println("" + firstnumber + " % " + secondnumber + " = " + moddivide);

    int average= sum / 2;  //find the average number of both numbers
    System.out.println("The average of you two number is: " + average);



    keyboard.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use inputdialog box

```
int firstnumber= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the first number"));

int secondnumber= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the second number"));

int sum=firstnumber+secondnumber;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"sum is ="+sum);
```

also you can write above code in a single line like

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"sum is ="+(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the first number"))+Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the first number"))));
```

Comment: wow thank you! but how can i make dialog for the result? i just use the same code?

Comment: yes, thank again!!  it work now and i had changed it to show the user input too: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"" + firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " +sum, "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

Comment: since it been change to user input and work perfectly does it possible to make it show multiple lines of the result in one dialog?

Comment: @bscouth yes just use \n for newline
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "First line\nSecond line");

Comment: sorry for asking but the \n seem doesnt work for me here the code i put:
int minus= firstnumber - secondnumber;
  int sum= firstnumber + secondnumber;  
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"" + firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " + sum +"/n" + firstnumber + " - " + secondnumber + " = " + minus,  "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

Comment: @bscouth you have done small mistake."/n" is not correct .you should put "\n" for newline .use backslash .then your code will work